# Replace emtpy fields with string of zero's in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column that either contains a string array with 512 elements or a missing value. I need to replace the missing value with an string array of zero's (also of length 512). A not so elegant, but working solution that I came up with is to is to use `coalesce` as follows:

```
 SELECT Identifier
, D.DataSource
, coalesce(Embedding, '[0,0,0,0,0,0]') as Embedding
FROM Documents D
LEFT OUTER JOIN DocumentEmbeddings DE
on DE.DocumentIdentifier = D.Identifier
```

Embedding is the field that contains the array or the null value. Coalesce successfully replaces the missing values with the string that I give as an input. In the code sample the array contains only 6 elements, this would in the real case need to be 512 zero's. How can I do this without just entering 512 zero's in there (separated by a comma)?

The equivalent in Python would be:

```
array = [0] * 512
```

Comment: This is not an array, this is a string. `concat('[', replicate('0,', 511), '0]')`.

Comment: Why perpetuate a bad design? If you have multiple data items, store them in the database structure *designed* to store multiple values - a table. Don't cram them all together in a string that you shove in one column.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Will look into alternative ways.